# Assign new point to a class using spectral clustering

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, clustering

Say I used spectral clustering to cluster a data-set $D$ of points $X_0 - X_n$ into a number $C$ of clusters. How can I efficiently assign a new single point $X_{n+1}$ to his convenient cluster?

Do I have to do the classification from the beginning (destroy all the clusters and apply the algorithm to the data-set $X_0 - X_{n+1}$), or is there an optimized way to extend to the point $X_{n+1}$?

Answer (score 1):

I think you do not, since I was able to find several papers that proposed algorithms for the same:

- [Incremental spectral clustering by efficiently updating the eigen-system](http://www.ifp.illinois.edu/~hning2/papers/incremental_spectral_clustering.pdf)
- [Incremental kernel spectral clustering for online learning of non-stationary data](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0925231214004433)
- [A Fast Incremental Spectral Clustering for Large Data Sets](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/PDCAT.2011.4)

Such algorithms are called *sequential*, *incremental*, *streaming*, or *online*. Armed with this knowledge, you can find more papers on your own.